# How to access the Scrollbars of a ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm trying to get some information about the `ScrollBar` components that are by standard included in a `ScrollPane`. Especially i'm interested in reading the `height` of the horizontal `Scrollbar`. How can i reference it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see how many vertical pixels the horizontal scrollbar uses or where it is placed or what?

Comment: I want to see how many vertical pixels the height of the ScrollBar is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the mentioned methods did not work for everybody (including me), I investigated it a bit more and found the source of the problem.

In general, both methods work, but only as soon as the [`ScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html)'s [`skin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#skinProperty) property has been set. In my case, `skin` was still `null` after loading my view using [`FXMLLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html).

By delaying the call in case the `skin` property has not been initialized (using a one-shot listener) solves the problem.

Working boiler-plate code:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane;
// ...
if (scrollPane.getSkin() == null) {
    // Skin is not yet attached, wait until skin is attached to access the scroll bars
    ChangeListener<Skin<?>> skinChangeListener = new ChangeListener<Skin<?>>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Skin<?>> observable, Skin<?> oldValue, Skin<?> newValue) {
            scrollPane.skinProperty().removeListener(this);
            accessScrollBar(scrollPane);
        }
    };
    scrollPane.skinProperty().addListener(skinChangeListener);
} else {
    // Skin is already attached, just access the scroll bars
    accessScrollBar(scrollPane);
}

private void accessScrollBar(ScrollPane scrollPane) {
    for (Node node : scrollPane.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
            ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
            if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                // Do something with the horizontal scroll bar

                // Example 1: Print scrollbar height
                // System.out.println(scrollBar.heightProperty().get());

                // Example 2: Listen to visibility changes
                // scrollBar.visibleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                //     if(newValue) {
                //         // Do something when scrollbar gets visible
                //     } else {
                //         // Do something when scrollbar gets hidden
                //     }
                // });
            }
            if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                // Do something with the vertical scroll bar
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: runlater is unsafe: there's no guarantee _when_ it is called, just _sometime later_ which may or may not after the skin is attached. Listening to the scrollPane's skin property and do the lookup after the first change is safe.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for the input! I updated the code to not use `Platform.runLater()` but to listen to a change to the `skin` property.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use the lookupAll() method of the Node class for find the scroll bars. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll(java.lang.String)

For example:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFxScrollPaneTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String longString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
        Text longText = TextBuilder.create().text(longString).build();

        ScrollPane scrollPane = ScrollPaneBuilder.create().content(longText).build();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 400, 100));
        primaryStage.show();

        Set<Node> nodes = scrollPane.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
        for (final Node node : nodes) {
            if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
                ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar) node;
                if (sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                    System.out.println("horizontal scrollbar visible = " + sb.isVisible());
                    System.out.println("width = " + sb.getWidth());
                    System.out.println("height = " + sb.getHeight());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me (JavaFX 8) in run-time –  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904312/how-to-access-scrollbar-in-a-scrollpane-javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904312/how-to-access-scrollbar-in-a-scrollpane-javafx).

Answer (score 5):

This not is the best pratice, but works,

```
private boolean determineVerticalSBVisible(final ScrollPane scrollPane) {
    try {
        final ScrollPaneSkin skin = (ScrollPaneSkin) scrollPane.getSkin();
        final Field field = skin.getClass().getDeclaredField("vsb");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        final ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) field.get(skin);
        field.setAccessible(false);
        return scrollBar.isVisible();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use "hsb" for Horizontal ScrollBar.

Best Regards,
Henrique Guedes.

Answer (score 1):

This also works, and I find it easier!

```
    scrollPane.skinProperty().addListener((skinObservable, oldSkin, newSkin) -> {

       if(newSkin != null) {

           ScrollBar hScrollBar = ((ScrollPaneSkin) newSkin).getHorizontalScrollBar();

           ScrollBar vScrollBar = ((ScrollPaneSkin) newSkin).getVerticalScrollBar();

           // Add event listeners to ScrollBars
           hScrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
               System.out.println("Horizontal Scroll Value: " + newValue);
           });

           vScrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
               System.out.println("Vertical Scroll Value: " + newValue);
           });

      }

  });
```