# How to resize JavaFX ScrollPane content to fit current size

Tags: resize, javafx, autolayout, scrollpane

I have a `BorderPane` with a `ScrollPane` as the center element. It resizes automatically to fill the screen. Inside the `ScrollPane` is a `HBox` that has no content but is a drag-and-drop target. Therefore I want it to fill its parent `ScrollPane`.

What is the preferred way to do this?

What I have tried so far is overriding the `ScrollPane.resize(...)` method to resize the `HBox` but it seems rather complicated and unorthodox.

edit: To add some useful code to this, this is how I can workaround the problem, but I believe there has to be some better way to do this:

```
@Override
public void resize(double width, double height) {
    super.resize(width, height);

    double scrollBarHeight = 2;
    double scrollBarWidth = 2;

    for (final Node node : lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
            ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar) node;
            if (sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                System.out.println("horizontal scrollbar visible = " + sb.isVisible());
                System.out.println("width = " + sb.getWidth());
                System.out.println("height = " + sb.getHeight());
                if(sb.isVisible()){
                    scrollBarHeight = sb.getHeight();
                }
            }
            if (sb.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                System.out.println("vertical scrollbar visible = " + sb.isVisible());
                System.out.println("width = " + sb.getWidth());
                System.out.println("height = " + sb.getHeight());
                if(sb.isVisible()){
                    scrollBarWidth = sb.getWidth();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    hBox.setPrefSize(width-scrollBarWidth, height-scrollBarHeight);
}
```

Code partly taken from here: [How to access the Scrollbars of a ScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678317/how-to-access-the-scrollbars-of-a-scrollpane)

Comment: It's ok, I just put a hgrow and vgrow to sometimes and it works now

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```

without overriding the `resize()` method.

Comment: Just as I thought, there had to be the obvious way that I just didn't find. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: What's the access method for setFitToHeight and setFitToWidth in xml?

Comment: @Andrew121007 it is `<ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true">`

Answer (score 32):

Setting the `fitToHeight` or `fitToWidth` attribute through `XML` or `CSS`:

FXML:

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="myScrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" />
```

CSS:

```
.my-scroll-pane {
    -fx-fit-to-height: true;
    -fx-fit-to-width: true;
}
```

Comment: I like using ScrollPane instead of something like .my-scroll-pane to make the whole thing automatic, no FXML changes needed then.. should probably be a default.

Comment: @Manius thats true, but you should be careful that you make it specific, otherwise all your scroll panes behave like the same and probably you do not want that.

Comment: Id like to add that this option is available in Scene Builder. In any Scroll Pane under 'layout' -> 'Specific' (second from the top) -> Fit To Width / Height. Took me a while to find hopefully this helps someone.